# Design Pattern Help - Composition and Code Re-use

Tags: oop, design-patterns, composition

I always seem to fall back on the Factory Pattern/Inheritance for code reuse, and have been reading about composition over inheritance and do see the benefits of the loose coupling.  You definitely get dependencies with inheritance.  So I am trying to wrap my head around a pattern for "process" objects.

They all basically,

- get their "environmental variables" from a database,
- Get a list of files,
- Process/convert each file (think convert XML to CSV), which entails

  - Reading the file, line by line
  - Writing a file into a another format, line by line
  - updating status (writing status to a database)

Get a list of files may mean get a list of files from a local directory, or get a list of files from a remote FTP site.

The thing that I'm struggling with, with compositoin is CODE REUSE.  Using inheritance, if I had a Base Abstract Class, I could put my GetEnvironment, UpdateStatus, methods in the base class and the child classes would get them for free.  How would I be able to get code reuse like this using composition? I could have helper classes, but I would essentially repeat the boilerplate use of these helper classes in each "process" class.  I can work up some pseudo code if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the details in the question, I would have my solution as follows:

- Environment

  - Domain object that holds the environment details.
- EnvironmentDAO and DBEnvironmentDAO

  - The interface and the DB-backed implementation to build the Environment domain object.
- AToBConverter

  - Takes a file and reference to the environment object
  - performs the transformation, writes to another file and updates the status in the DB
- Launcher

  - Takes a list of files.
  - Retrieves the Environment from the database using the DAO.
  - Employs a scalable mechanim (like ExecutorService) to run the AToBConverters in parallel.